# How to prevent auto firing RadioButtonList indexchange event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have a radioButton list and I want to set 0 as default index.
But,when page is posted by other button ,radiobuttonListChanged event is firing automaticly.

What should I do ?

```
 protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       rblList.DataSource = MyDataSource();
       rblList.DataBind ();
        if (!IsPostBack)
         {
           rblAccounts.SelectedIndex = 0;
         }
     }

    protected void rbl_Changed (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write("Change Event fired");
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to prevent it you set selectedindex to 0 in page load first time

Comment: Ahmed Yousif Because I want to show data. data depends on selectedvalue.

Comment: could you please explain more your use case because it not clear enough

Comment: Well,I have a radiobuttonlist and a DataGrid.Datasource of DataGrid depend upon selectedValue of radioButtonList.
Thus I set 0  as a Default selected value for  datasource of DataGrid.Even though I checked  the page is IsPostBack,radioButtonListevent is called automaticly When I click to the  pagination. But I want to change grid's datasource with radiobutton's SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: As i understand when user change  rbl selected index you postback the page to change datasource of the datagridview so you set this rbl to be autopostback control so why when you postback the page by any another button  SelectedIndexChanged event fired?

Comment: I guess you do not understand me.When I'm changing gridview page index,rbl_Changed event is triggering. Any button of page fires this event (rbl_Changed). why?

Comment: firing rbl SelectedIndexChanged mean that user changed selected radio button but rbl is't autopostback so when Any button of page clicked by default buttons autopostback fires this event

Answer (score 1):

In rbl_Changed event Write following code probably will help you out.

```
rbl.changed-= rbl_Changed;
rbl.changed = false;
rbl.changed+= rbl_Changed;
```

Comment: If it help you out kindly accept this solution as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer but I couldn't find "rb.changed" boolean property. are you sure ? I tried your code.but it isn't working.

Comment: Check auto post back event of radio button if exist in HTML make it false.